# Smooth scrolling to internal links within div acting strangely; possibly a CSS sizing/spacing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a `div` that uses `overflow:hidden` and is within several other `div` containers. I am trying to scroll to internal links within the `div` using smooth scrolling via jQuery. Here is my code, which I have used on other projects with good results:

```js
$(function() {
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('#cardb').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset(
                ).top
         }, 0500);
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2vh 3vw;
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#slide4 {
    background: #ddd;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 2.5vw;
}
#carda, #cardb {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 60vh;
    padding: 3vw;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    float: left;
}
#cardb {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#cardb-1, #cardb-2, #cardb-3, #cardb-4 {
    position: relative;
    height: 60vh;
}
#linkcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20vh;
}
.linkcircle {
    height: 3vh;
    width: 3vh;
    margin: 1vh;
    background: #999;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.35s;
    border-radius: 1.5vh;
}
.linkcircle:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide4" class="slide">
  <div id="carda">
    <p>CARD A</p>
  </div>
          <div id="cardb">
                <div id="cardb-1">
                    <p>CARD B 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="cardb-2">
                    <p>CARD B 2</p>
                </div>
                <div id="cardb-3">
                    <p>CARD B 3</p>
                </div>
                <div id="cardb-4">
                    <p>CARD B 4</p>
                </div>
              
              <div id="linkcontainer">
                  <a href="#cardb-1"><div class="linkcircle"></div></a>
                  <a href="#cardb-2"><div class="linkcircle"></div></a>
                  <a href="#cardb-3"><div class="linkcircle"></div></a>
                  <a href="#cardb-4"><div class="linkcircle"></div></a>
              </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am baffled by the results - the links almost never scroll to the correct target, and clicking the same link twice still scrolls (e.g. when you are at `#cardb-1` and click the link for `#cardb-1` again, the div scrolls somewhere else). I'm new to jQuery, but I've researched as much as I could figure out, with no improvement. I suspect it might actually be a CSS problem, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong with that either. The links come up fine at the expected position when I deactivate the jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking to solve this exact problem, I have taken your code as a start, so thanks.

In order to solve the scroll from happening again when clicking on the same link, I have include this code at the beginning of the function:

```
if( location.hash == this.hash){ return false;}
```

Although, it seems to take the process 1 or 2 seconds to settle in the new hash, so if you click twice on the same link withing that time lapse, the problem still persists, but if you click after that period nothing happens.  I am still trying to figure out if I can eliminate the 1-2 seconds refreshing lapse, but at least it's a beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code that will scroll to the right place.
The trick is that the animated function takes an absolute y, and the original code only accounts for the top, which does not include the margins, and there is another 100px added (in my page) which I am not sure where it's coming from.  So I just iterate through all divs until I reach the sought one, and calculate its position along the way.  This also fixes the behavior when you click rapidly on two links.

```
     $(function() {
        $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
            if( location.hash == this.hash){ return false;}
            var target = $(this.hash);

            var targetId = this.hash.substr(1);
            var toGo = 0;

            // class of each div that has an id for anchor link.
            $('.info-box').each(function() {
                var box = $(this);

                if( this.id == targetId){
                    toGo += box.outerHeight(true)-box.outerHeight();
                    return false;
                }
                toGo += box.outerHeight(true)-box.outerHeight();
                toGo += box.outerHeight();
            });

            if (target.length) {
                // id of the container div  
                $('#page').animate({scrollTop: toGo}, 700);
                return false;
            }
        });
     });
```

Comment: I just noticed that you can just use  toGo += box.outerHeight(true),  instead of the two lines adding the margin and then the height.